# How to code a Chrome Extension where any image from the project folder can be generated

Tags: javascript, html, image, google-chrome-extension, generator

I'm working on a project for a Chrome Extension image generate. How do I code a Chrome Extension where any image from the project folder can be generated? This is my code so far:

```js
//popup.js

var images = ["img/1.jpg", "img/2.jpg", "img/3.jpg", "img/4.jpg", "img/5.jpg", "img/6.jpg"];

var randomName = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];

document.getElementById("randomImage").style.backgroundImage = "url('/images" + randomName + "')";
```

```html
<!--popup.html-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>47</title></head>
<body>
    <div id="randomImage"/>
    
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</html>
```

And the manifest.json file:

```
    {
    "name" : "47",
    "description" : "爸爸，生日快乐！",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version" : "2.0",
    "background": {
    "scripts": "popup.js"
  },
    "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },

    "browser_action" : {
        "default_popup" : "popup.html",
        "default_icon" : "img/icon.png"
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a project folder? Can you elaborate with an example on "any image can be generated"?

Comment: The project folder is the folder that is contained within the entire folder of files. Example: This project is called Image Generator, and inside are two folders, one with all the code and one with all the images. I would like to generate an image from the image folder without having to write out the whole array. And the image folder is local, not a url.

Comment: In Chrome you can use chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry, look for examples.